# Untarring a moved file with Shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to untar a file that has been moved to another folder inside a for loop. This is what I've got this so far:

```
#! /bin/bash


for f in *.tar
do
   mv C:/Users/x/Documents/$f C:/Users/x/Documents/folder
   tar xvf "$f" -C C:/Users/x/Documents/folder
done
```

which throws an error about the file that I'm wishing to untar not existing. Since I moved it I thought that untarring it at that location would work. Any help is appreciated! Sorry about this very basic question, shell is totally alien to me.

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: tar files.tar: Cannot open: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for f in *.tar
```

Loops over each Tar file in the *current* directory, which...

```
mv C:/Users/x/Documents/$f C:/Users/x/Documents/folder
```

...is assuming that you are currently in `C:/Users/x/Documents/`, or the whole script will not make sense. (Bad coding, should probably be `for f in C:/Users/x/Documents/*.tar` or somesuch, but we will work with your script as-is for the scope of this answer.)

So now you moved the tarball into `folder` (if that exists), or you *renamed* it to `folder` if that didn't exist. (Could have checked for existence, or written with a trailing slash as `.../folder/` to at least get an error message if it doesn't exist.)

Anyway...

```
tar xvf "$f" -C C:/Users/x/Documents/folder
```

...now you are trying to extract the file `$f` **which you just moved away**, which of course yields...

```
Cannot open: No such file or directory
```

Either do this...

```
tar xvf "folder/$f" -C C:/Users/x/Documents/folder
```

...or do a `cd` into `folder` before you untar:

```
cd folder && tar xvf "$f" && cd -
```